# how to handle unique fields while cloning?

Tags: apex, clone

I have developed below code fro cloning but unfortunately because of unique field i am getting error of duplication.

here one text field set to unique.

Apex class:

```
    public class GSDPartnerCloneWithSkillsController {

    public ApexPages.StandardController controller {get; set;}
    public GSD_Partner__c GSDP {get;set;}
    public ID newRecordId {get;set;}
    public Id OldGSDResourceId {get;set;}
    public Id NewGSDResourceId {get;set;}


    public GSDPartnerCloneWithSkillsController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

        this.controller = controller;
        GSDP = (GSD_Partner__c)controller.getRecord();

    }

    public PageReference cloneWithItems() {

         Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
         GSD_Partner__c newGSDP;

         try {

             GSDP = (GSD_Partner__c) GSDDataUtility.getObject('GSD_Partner__c', GSDP.id);

             newGSDP = GSDP.clone(false);
             insert newGSDP;


             newRecordId = newGSDP.id;


             GSD_Resource__c OldGSDResource = [select id from  GSD_Resource__c where Partner__c = :GSDP.id limit 1];
             OldGSDResourceId = OldGSDResource.id;
             system.debug('OldGSDResourceId :'+OldGSDResourceId );

             GSD_Resource__c NewGSDResource = [select id from  GSD_Resource__c where Partner__c = :newRecordId  limit 1];
             NewGSDResourceId = NewGSDResource.id;
             system.debug('NewGSDResourceId :'+NewGSDResourceId);

             CLoneGSDResourceLang();
             CLoneGSDResourceNon();
             CLoneGSDResourcePPS();
             CLoneGSDResourcePMaster();
             CLoneGSDResourceServices();
             CLoneGSDResourceTech();

         } catch (Exception e){
            Database.rollback(sp);
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            return null;
         }

        return new PageReference('/'+newGSDP.id+'/e?retURL=%2F'+newGSDP.id);
    }

    public void CLoneGSDResourceLang(){

        List<GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c> InsertnewSkillList = new List<GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c>();
        List<GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c> SkillsList = [select id,Skill_Name__c,Skill_Category__c,Standard__c,Stand_By__c,Non_Product_Skill_Level__c,Web_App_Resp_Created_Dt__c,Web_App_Resp_Modified_Dt__c,Responsibility_Skill_Level__c,Web_App_Employee_Id__c,Web_App_ID__c,Web_App_Skill_Id__c from GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c where Skill_Category__c = :Label.GSDResourceLang and Resource_ID__c = :OldGSDResourceId];  
        if(!SkillsList.isEmpty()){
            for (GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c GSDrskill : SkillsList) {
                  GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c newGSDrskill  = GSDrskill.clone(false);
                  newGSDrskill.Resource_ID__c = NewGSDResourceId;
                  InsertnewSkillList.add(newGSDrskill);
            }
            system.debug('InsertnewSkillList:'+InsertnewSkillList);
            insert InsertnewSkillList ;
        }
    }

    public void CLoneGSDResourceNon(){

        List<GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c> InsertnewSkillList = new List<GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c>();
        List<GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c> SkillsList = [select id,Skill_Name__c,Skill_Category__c,Standard__c,Stand_By__c,Non_Product_Skill_Level__c,Web_App_Resp_Created_Dt__c,Web_App_Resp_Modified_Dt__c,Responsibility_Skill_Level__c,Web_App_Employee_Id__c,Web_App_ID__c,Web_App_Skill_Id__c from GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c where Skill_Category__c = :Label.GSDResourceNon and Resource_ID__c = :OldGSDResourceId];  
        if(!SkillsList.isEmpty()){
            for (GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c GSDrskill : SkillsList) {
                  GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c newGSDrskill  = GSDrskill.clone(false);
                  newGSDrskill.Resource_ID__c = NewGSDResourceId;
                  InsertnewSkillList.add(newGSDrskill);
            }
            system.debug('InsertnewSkillList:'+InsertnewSkillList);
            insert InsertnewSkillList ;
        }
    }

    public void CLoneGSDResourcePPS(){

        List<GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c> InsertnewSkillList = new List<GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c>();
        List<GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c> SkillsList = [select id,Skill_Name__c,Skill_Category__c,Standard__c,Stand_By__c,Non_Product_Skill_Level__c,Web_App_Resp_Created_Dt__c,Web_App_Resp_Modified_Dt__c,Responsibility_Skill_Level__c,Web_App_Employee_Id__c,Web_App_ID__c,Web_App_Skill_Id__c from GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c where Skill_Category__c = :Label.GSDResourcePPS and Resource_ID__c = :OldGSDResourceId];  
        if(!SkillsList.isEmpty()){
            for (GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c GSDrskill : SkillsList) {
                  GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c newGSDrskill  = GSDrskill.clone(false);
                  newGSDrskill.Resource_ID__c = NewGSDResourceId;
                  InsertnewSkillList.add(newGSDrskill);
            }
            system.debug('InsertnewSkillList:'+InsertnewSkillList);
            insert InsertnewSkillList ;
        }
    }

    public void CLoneGSDResourcePMaster(){

        List<GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c> InsertnewSkillList = new List<GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c>();
        List<GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c> SkillsList = [SELECT Id, Name, Skill_Name__r.Name, Responsibility_Skill_Level__c, Skill_Name__r.Product_Description__c, Skill_Name__r.Portfolio__c FROM GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c WHERE Resource_ID__c = :OldGSDResourceId AND Skill_Category__c =: Label.GSDResourcePMaster ];
        if(!SkillsList.isEmpty()){
            for (GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c GSDrskill : SkillsList) {
                  GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c newGSDrskill  = GSDrskill.clone(false);
                  newGSDrskill.Resource_ID__c = NewGSDResourceId;
                  InsertnewSkillList.add(newGSDrskill);
            }
            system.debug('InsertnewSkillList:'+InsertnewSkillList);
            insert InsertnewSkillList ;
        }
    }

    public void CLoneGSDResourceServices(){

        List<GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c> InsertnewSkillList = new List<GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c>();
        List<GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c> SkillsList = [SELECT Id, Name, Skill_Name__r.Name, Responsibility_Skill_Level__c, Skill_Name__r.Product_Description__c, Skill_Name__r.Portfolio__c, Skill_Name__r.Support_Activity__c,Standard__c, Stand_By__c FROM GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c WHERE Resource_ID__c = :OldGSDResourceId AND Skill_Category__c ='Services' ];
        if(!SkillsList.isEmpty()){
            for (GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c GSDrskill : SkillsList) {
                  GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c newGSDrskill  = GSDrskill.clone(false);
                  newGSDrskill.Resource_ID__c = NewGSDResourceId;
                  InsertnewSkillList.add(newGSDrskill);
            }
            system.debug('InsertnewSkillList:'+InsertnewSkillList);
            insert InsertnewSkillList ;
        }
    }

    public void CLoneGSDResourceTech(){

        List<GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c> InsertnewSkillList = new List<GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c>();
        List<GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c> SkillsList = [SELECT Id, Name, Responsibility_Skill_Level__c, Skill_Name__r.Name, Skill_Name__r.Technologies_Name__c FROM GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c WHERE Resource_ID__c =:OldGSDResourceId  AND Skill_Category__c =: Label.GSDResourceTech ];
        if(!SkillsList.isEmpty()){
            for (GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c GSDrskill : SkillsList) {
                  GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c newGSDrskill  = GSDrskill.clone(false);
                  newGSDrskill.Resource_ID__c = NewGSDResourceId;
                  InsertnewSkillList.add(newGSDrskill);
            }
            system.debug('InsertnewSkillList:'+InsertnewSkillList);
            insert InsertnewSkillList ;
        }
    }
}
```

apex class:

```
  public class GSDDataUtility {
public static sObject getObject(string objName, string id) {

    String fieldnames = '';
    sObject obj;
    try {
        Map < String, Schema.SObjectType > m = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
        Schema.SObjectType s = m.get(objName);
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult r = s.getDescribe();


        Map < String, Schema.SObjectField > fields = r.fields.getMap();
        for (string field: fields.keySet()) {
            if (fieldnames == '') {
                fieldnames = field;
            } else {
                fieldnames += ',' + field;
            }
        }


        String sql = 'SELECT ' + fieldnames + ' FROM ' + objName + ' WHERE Id=\'' + id + '\'';
        System.debug(sql);
        obj = database.query(sql);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.debug('get Fields Error' + e.getMessage());
        ApexPages.addMessages(e);
        return null;
    }
    return obj;
}
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case you need to use Schema class.
After collecting all fields you need to check they "unique" parameter.
There is method called "isUnique()".

```
for (Schema.SObjectField field : fields.values()) {
    if(field.getDescribe().isUnique()){
        //change value
    } 
}
```

Comment: hey artur , how to add that change value logic..because we taking foeld as string..

Comment: Sorry - my mistake I copied your code and forgot to change loop... You should go trough values of map not its keys. So you should iterate on SObjectField list. I will update my answer. Sorry for confusion